# Service for email form for a webpage

Tags: javascript, email, saas

I need to put "contact us" form on a static webpage. I want to create the form myself, but I can't send emails from JavaScript. However, I can send HTTP requests. So I want to send request with all the data necessary to some service, and I want this service to send me an email.

I know SendGrid or Mandrill, but I don't want to create a gate for spammers. Obviously, if I used services like this my API-KEY would be publicly accessible in JS files. Unless it is possible to limit this services to send emails only to one address, but I couldn't find such option.

Another options are http://kontactr.com/ or http://www.emailmeform.com but they offer whole web form, and send complicated requests with some ID, which doesn't work when sent again. I.e. I can't forge working request myself. Also, Kontactr comes with captcha, which I don't want and can not remove.

Do you know any simple service I could use? I want it to be as simple as possible - just data in a request which then are sent to my email.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I think answers for such questions can be only opinionated.... For spam, we can always downvote.

I often find recommendations for programming libraries here, so why not other services?

Comment: Sure, but I copied & pasted from [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using SendGrid and Parse as outlined in this blog post: https://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-static-websites-using-parse

Using Parse allows you to keep things like your SendGrid API key a secret.

Additionally, you can make it more spam resistant by adding a Captcha, either something you create yourself, or some of the services out there ([reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html), [Sweetcaptcha](http://sweetcaptcha.com/), or others).

Comment: I wouldn't use it(sweetcaptcha) at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html